# How to configure Thunderbird for local offline usage?

Tags: command-line, email, gui, thunderbird, alpine-mail

How would `Thunderbird` send such a [message](https://superuser.com/a/1818417/977796)?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ swaks --to tbird@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech --from nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech --server localhost
=== Trying localhost:25...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 mordor.saundersconsulting.tech ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
 -> EHLO mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
<-  250-mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250-DSN
<-  250-SMTPUTF8
<-  250 CHUNKING
 -> MAIL FROM:<nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<tbird@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Mon, 27 Nov 2023 15:57:05 -0800
 -> To: tbird@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
 -> From: nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
 -> Subject: test Mon, 27 Nov 2023 15:57:05 -0800
 -> Message-Id: <20231127155705.1481920@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20201014.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 -> 
 -> This is a test mailing
 -> 
 -> 
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 0BA3237E
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Assuming everything is local and offline.  Just looking to send e-mails from one user to another, but with `Thunderbird` rather than `mailutils` or `pine` etc.

The recipient:

```
  ALPINE 2.25   MESSAGE INDEX                                                                      Folder: INBOX                                                                       Message 3 of 3      

+     1 15:48      nicholas                                                   (568) ping                                                                                                                   
+     2 15:57      nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech                    (717) test Mon, 27 Nov 2023 15:57:05 -0800                                                                                   
+     3 15:58      nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech                    (717) test Mon, 27 Nov 2023 15:58:13 -0800
```

so the messages are working as expected.  Thunderbird:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]